# WP Theme Button not re-sizing on mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile

I'm building a website on WordPress using the Stockholm Theme. Generally it's mobile responsive and most things work quite well.
One thing that's causing me trouble is 'buttons'.

There's an example on the following page:
https://med4eu.co.uk/proces

It doesn't display correctly on mobile. The width is too long and goes off the page. I'm trying to figure out how I can make it go into multiple lines (so text spread over 2 lines instead of 1, where necessary, to fit on the screen).
Happy to consider other solutions you might suggest as well.

Here's what it looks like on mobile:

[image: Screenshot of display on iPhone]

You can view source code on the above link.

Help much appreciated, as always! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add only for mobile media query this property to "a tag" button:

```
white-space: normal;
display: block;
height: auto;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That got me part of the way there,
 but the container didn't expand seemingly so the button border didn't change and the text went onto the next row (same blue colour bg as font)
 [link]https://med4eu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/update1.jpg

Comment: Nevermind, I'd actually added the code to the wrong property tag. Worked really well! thank you :)